# UPDATED: trying to store an array in php then call a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to store results in an array from mysql using php, then using the results to call a javascript function to use the results there. I'm not sure why my map isn't showing up (trying to implement google maps into my page)

My php/html/javascript call

```
 <?php
.....
<div id="content"
           ......

$address=array();
//will list out where to go
while ($sec = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $address[$x++] = ($sec[5] . " " . $sec[7]);
}
print_r($latlng);
print_r($address);
mysql_close($link);
?>

<div id="address_container">
<?php
print array_shift($address);
?>
</div>
</div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOp$
  }

function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementByID("address_container").innerHTML;
console.log(address);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + s$
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the HTML element with ID `address`? What format are you trying to use to transfer the data from PHP to javascript? I think you need to use/are missing a call to [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)... As it is you are passing in a reference to the HTML element itself, which can't be right? Can it? Not big on Google maps but I can't believe that is what it is expecting...

Comment: I'm trying to input an array of addresses... example. Array ( [1] => 1251 Front Street Lahaina, HI 96761 [2] => 160 Keonekai Rd Hihei, HI 96753 )   . then input it into javascript to turn these addresses in for putting a marker on the map.  but now my map isn't showing up either...

Answer (score 1):

See if this produces the result you are expecting:

PHP:

```
<?php

  // ......

  $address = array();
  while ($sec = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) $address[++$x]= "$sec[5] $sec[7]";

  // this should print the same data as you were getting before if you un-comment it
  // print_r($address);
  mysql_close($link);

?>
<div id="address_container"><?php print array_shift($address); ?></div>
</div> <!-- I left this here because I don't know what the rest of your HTML looks like... -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(codeAddress());
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementByID("address_container").innerHTML;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: err it as my fault that my map wasn't showing up. (doh!!). but with the function codeAddress() it's still not putting the marker on the map. therefore making me believe that the function isn't being called???

Comment: @pythono Are you getting any output from the `console.log(address);` line? And also, do you get anything if you add the line `alert('Callback function called');` as the first line of the callback (before the `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {` line)?

Comment: hi daverandom, I am not getting any output for either using:

Comment: 'console.log(address); alert('Callback function called'); if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'

Answer (score 0):

don't print_r $address, but echo it into a js var

```
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var address = <?php echo json_encode($address); ?> ;
document.write(codeAddress());
</script>
```

then no need to select it in your function

Comment: While this was my immediate thought, after a bit of reading on the subject it seems that the function expects a string with a human readable address. It looks to me like the OP's code has been lifted from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingStatusCodes).

Comment: Am I suppose to see anything on my website when I insert the "echo json_encode($address);" statement? Or What does that do? Sorry for my nuisance, I'm new to javascript.

Comment: it's doesn't show anything on the page, as the data is put inside a JS variable. You can see what's in with `console.log(address);` in the script session, and displaying the console (chrome) or firebug (firefox)

Comment: is my javascript code correct? just use "var address = document.getElementByID("address"); "

Answer (score 0):

This was what example I was going off from... from the google api

```
var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>
</body>
```

ref: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingAddressTypes